# What happened to StackMovies Twitter account?

Tags: discussion

It says [here](https://twitter.com/StackMovies/):

> Account suspended
>
> Twitter suspends accounts which violate the Twitter Rules

A screenshot:

> [image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue recently came up on the main Meta as well. I'm quoting an [answer by @double-beep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358514/295232):

> It seems that Twitter suddenly and randomly started blocking those accounts because they were bots posting automated tweets and that resulted in SE [not creating new Twitter accounts for new sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548) since 2015. It's still not known why Twitter has deleted [only some of the accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358449/why-is-stackchess-account-blocked-on-twitter/358514#comment1197036_358449).

Answer (score 6):

Tracing through the links in @Glorfiendel's answer, I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/389220) answer which gives a little more info:

> Not all (Stack Exchange) sites have Twitter accounts. We stopped creating them for all public beta sites by default because a) Twitter sees very little engagement for us; b) Twitter-the-company started blocking new accounts for us (probably because it thinks we're bots?) and fighting that got too annoying and time-consuming.